# java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError: java/lang/Object: Unsupported major.min or version 52.0

Tags: java, javafx

I made a utility in using javafx on my system with jdk1.8 installed. Now I need to run this on my server it has jdk1.6. So while running this utility, I am getting error as,

```
Error occured during the initialization of vm
java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError: java/lang/Object : Unsupported major.min
or version 52.0
```

So can anybody please tell is there any possible way to run it on existing jdk1.6 without installing jdk1.6.

Comment: since JavaFX didn't exist in Java 6, I doubt it. Even if it did, you would have to compile it using a Java 6 compiler, not a Java 8 one.

Comment: are you using eclipse??

Comment: Yes I agree with @Stultuske try to compile it with jdk1.6 and then try to deploy it.

Comment: @Haseeb Yes I made program using eclipse

Comment: @stultuske okie I would try that

Comment: @Stultuske JavaFX was (is) available with Java 6. This downloads can still be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx2-archive-download-1939373.html). Nevertheless, using these are not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your jdk version in eclipse as:

You manage the list of available compilers in the Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE's tab.

In the project build path configuration dialog, under the libraries tab, you can delete the entry for "JRE System Library", click on "Add Library" and choose the installed JRE to compile with. Some compilers can be configured to compile at a back-level compiler version.